# Case Statement not working in PSQUERY Where Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, case, decode

I have  a field bill type id which has suppose x, y and z values. Bill Type ID is a prompt and the condition is when psquery is run and if bill type id value is blank then it should return all the rows with bill type id x,y and z.

Following is the case Statement and Decode function written:

```
(CASE 
WHEN A.BILL_TYPE_ID = ' ' THEN A.BILL_TYPE_ID LIKE ' %' 
ELSE A.BILL_TYPE_ID = :3 
END ))
```

EDIT (from comment):

```
SELECT 
  C.NAME1, 
  TO_CHAR(A.FROM_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD'), 
  B.LINE_SEQ_NUM,  
  B.IDENTIFIER,  
  B.DESCR,  
  B.GROSS_EXTENDED_AMT,  
  A.INVOICE_AMOUNT, 
  C.SETID, 
  C.CUST_ID 
FROM PS_BI_HDR A, PS_BI_LINE B, PS_CUSTOMER C 
WHERE 
( 
  A.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT 
  AND A.INVOICE = B.INVOICE 
  AND A.BILL_TO_CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID 
  AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = :1 
  AND A.BILL_STATUS = :2 
  AND 
  ( 
    A.BILL_TYPE_ID = 
    (
      CASE 
        WHEN A.BILL_TYPE_ID = ' ' THEN A.BILL_TYPE_ID LIKE ' %' 
        ELSE A.BILL_TYPE_ID = :3 
      END 
    )
  ) 
) ORDER BY 1, 3
```

With above case statement I am getting error: Missing Keyword and I am not able to debug which keyword is missing. Please advise.

```
Decode(:3,' ','%',:3)
```

Using Decode function I am not getting error but when bill type id is blank then it does not return any rows. Please help.

Comment: Please show us the complete statement. The `LIKE` operator in the `CASE` clause does not make any sense.

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression* - it's meant to compute a scalar value. It's *not* some form of control flow statement.

Comment: SELECT C.NAME1,  TO_CHAR(A.FROM_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD'), B.LINE_SEQ_NUM, B.IDENTIFIER, B.DESCR, B.GROSS_EXTENDED_AMT, A.INVOICE_AMOUNT,C.SETID,C.CUST_ID 
  FROM PS_BI_HDR A, PS_BI_LINE B, PS_CUSTOMER C 
  WHERE ( A.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT 
     AND A.INVOICE = B.INVOICE 
     AND A.BILL_TO_CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID 
     AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = :1 
     AND A.BILL_STATUS = :2 
     AND ( A.BILL_TYPE_ID = (CASE 
WHEN  A.BILL_TYPE_ID = ' ' THEN  A.BILL_TYPE_ID LIKE ' %' 
ELSE  A.BILL_TYPE_ID = :3 
END )) ) 
  ORDER BY 1, 3

Comment: What should I write in Case Statement if Like cannot be used to include all the values of bill type id

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - as you may have noticed, it's practically unreadable. There's an edit link at the bottom of your question (but it looks like StevieG has already been kind enough to edit it in this time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case where the input list is empty, you could just compare `A.BILL_TYPE_ID` to itself:

```
SELECT 
  C.NAME1, 
  TO_CHAR(A.FROM_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD'), 
  B.LINE_SEQ_NUM,  
  B.IDENTIFIER,  
  B.DESCR,  
  B.GROSS_EXTENDED_AMT,  
  A.INVOICE_AMOUNT, 
  C.SETID, 
  C.CUST_ID 
FROM PS_BI_HDR A, PS_BI_LINE B, PS_CUSTOMER C 
WHERE 
( 
  A.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT 
  AND A.INVOICE = B.INVOICE 
  AND A.BILL_TO_CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID 
  AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = :1 
  AND A.BILL_STATUS = :2 
  AND 
  ( 
    A.BILL_TYPE_ID = 
    (
      CASE 
        WHEN :3 = ' ' THEN A.BILL_TYPE_ID
        ELSE :3 
      END 
    )
  ) 
) ORDER BY 1, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

in where clause you can use case like this:

```
WHERE
A.BILL_TYPE_ID = (CASE WHEN A.BILL_TYPE_ID = ' ' THEN ' %' ELSE  ' 3' END)
```